# Sistemas WEB Qual a melhor forma de fugir do Buscadores e torna-lo invisível

Tags: segurança, algoritmo-de-busca, erp, robots.txt

Se tratando de sistemas WEB Qual seria e forma mais segura e mais utilizada para que ele se tornem invisíveis a motores de busca? sei que existe os "Metas" mais creio que deva haver forma mais confiaveis

Answer (score 4):

Antes de indexarem um site os motores de busca em geral procuram um arquivo chamado **robots.txt** e respeitam as diretrizes contidas nesse arquivo.

Exemplo: antes de visitar www.meusistema.com o crawler irá buscar www.meusistema.com/robots.txt

Você pode dizer que o site não deve ser indexado colocando o seguinte conteúdo no robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Você também pode permitir que o site seja indexado com exceções:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /protegido/
Disallow: /secreto/
```

**Um cuidado nesse ultimo caso:** Ao mesmo tempo que você está impedindo que essas pastas sejam indexadas você também está tornando "publico" que elas existem.

Robôs mal intencionados não irão respeitar essas diretivas e provalvelmente enviarão uma string User-Agent como se fossem um navegador comum, nesse caso apenas [CAPTCHAs](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) poderão impedi-los, mas essa é uma solução mais intrusiva já que os usuários verdadeiros também são afetados.

Comment: +1 porque está tudo certo. Só como complemento eu acrescentaria que há na web os *geradores de robots*, que podem ajudar muito aqueles que não estão familiarizados com isso.